# SSIS DB2-> SQL Server data migration issue (Timestamp -> DateTime2)

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

we are trying to transfer data from DB2 -> SQL Server 2014 database. When using SSIS to transfer data between tables, the timestamp -> datetime2 is failing due to data type mismatch. Found couple of links related to that, but not sure if they have the source db2 Timestamp column data converted to  string format before applying those conversions or data is coming in as Timestamp type and those conversions could still work?

please share how to handle this Timestamp -> Datetime2 mismatch in SSIS.

1) http://blog.appliedis.com/2012/09/24/best-practices-staging-mainframedb2-data-to-sql-server-2012-2/

2) https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/33eabd7d-b4ff-49b0-b053-ecfc575414ab/db2-timestamp-to-sql-server-2005-conversion?forum=sqlintegrationservices

regards
aravias

Comment: The second link is pretty clear: convert it to string in the DB2 side (they suggest using a derived column), truncate the last three digits (ffffff -> fff) and then convert it to DateTime2 on the SQL Server side.  Have you tried that yet?

Comment: actually the DBA is performing this task and stuck with that error, reached out to us for help, so I was trying to find some suggestions for him. In our case we are mapping to datetime2 and not datetime, so that truncation should not be required thats my understanding, I am assuming instead of (DT_DBTIMESTAMP2,3)[Column_Name],   it would be just (DT_DBTIMESTAMP2)[Column_Name], is that right?.   Will ask him to try above if that sounds right.  By the way, what woudl be conversion expression for converting db2 timestamp column data  to string in the source?

Comment: also to mention, the precision of the timestamp column type in DB2 is set to 6.