# How to convert DB2 timestamp to SQL Server datetime2?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, db2

I am converting DB2 stored procedures to SQL Server. One of the common issue is that DB2 use a time date format `timestamp` very commonly, for which the closest SQL Server equivalent appears to be `datetime2`.

What is an easy way to convert DB2 `timestamp` to `datetime2`?

---

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36222378/1050256) but there was not any answer.

Answer (score 3):

DB2 `timestamp` is very similar to SQL Server `datetime2`, except a hyphen and using periods instead of colons.

You can use `stuff()` to change those characters and then `convert()` to `datetime2`.

Examples:

```
declare @DB2_timpstamp varchar(30)
declare @SQL_datetime2 datetime2
set @DB2_timpstamp = '2019-02-02-11.22.33.456789'

set @SQL_datetime2 = try_convert(datetime2, stuff(stuff(stuff(@DB2_timpstamp, 17, 1, ':'), 14, 1, ':'), 11, 1, ' '))
select @SQL_datetime2
```